# How can I set up a mysql slave in Docker?

Tags: mysql, tcp, docker

I have a vagrant VM (192.168.50.4) running Ubuntu 14.04 with MySQL master (listening on 0.0.0.0:3306).

I would like to set up a slave inside a Docker container.

I've managed to do this, but I can't get the slave to communicate with the master on port 3306 for the purposes of replication:

```
root@foo:/# telnet 172.17.42.1 3306
Trying 172.17.42.1...
```

I've run nmap in the container, and this is what's returned:

```
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp  open   ssh
80/tcp  open   http
443/tcp closed https
```

What do I need to do to expose the *host*'s port 3306 to the docker container?

This is the vagrant vm's ifconfig:

```
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00  
          inet addr:172.17.42.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::38a1:35ff:fe62:4e9e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7876 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8191 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:347285 (347.2 KB)  TX bytes:6942124 (6.9 MB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:88:0c:a6  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe88:ca6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:50125 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:30588 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:31195565 (31.1 MB)  TX bytes:2403896 (2.4 MB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:e2:69:80  
          inet addr:192.168.50.4  Bcast:192.168.50.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fee2:6980/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:581794 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:382149 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:635183165 (635.1 MB)  TX bytes:61880252 (61.8 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:1938 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1938 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:326572 (326.5 KB)  TX bytes:326572 (326.5 KB)
```

And netstat:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11211         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:47056           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6099            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2812          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53276           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5666            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8100          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 192.168.50.4:1015       192.168.50.1:2049       TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:22            10.0.2.2:54474          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:22            10.0.2.2:54371          ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::5001                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::55344                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::6099                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::50244                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN
```

Answer (score 0):

I realised that an iptables configuration was opening ports 22, 80 and 443 and closing all others.  After adding port 3306 to iptables I could communicate with the host.